# When instantiating a PHP, there arguments that a passed as for instance

Tags: php, codeigniter

When Instantiating a class, sometimes there are params/arguments that are passed to that class constructor

```
class MyLibrary{
    function __construct($param1, $param2, $param3){
      /*
      * do something with those params
      * Here im setting "something" to be $param3 instead of param1 nor param2
      */
      $this->something = $param3; //I used param three to clarify my question
    }
}
```

The class constructor relies on those argument to run so in Codeigniter, they state that arguments must be passed in a form of an array when using

```
$arg = ['param1' => '1', 'param2' => '2', 'param3' => '3'];

$this->load->library('MyLibrary', $arg, 'custom_name');
```

So my question is, how do I pass those params in a sequence that the constructor is expecting them in Codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the array `$arg` you define above

```
$this->something = $arg['param3'];
```

If your question is "How do I define a custom class that accepts arguments to `__construct` that can be loaded using `$this->load->library()`?" The answer is to use an associative array for the argument. The `load' class only allows for a single argument so you have to use an array to pass multiple values.

All the core libraries use associative arrays to pass arguments to class constructors.

Your library must be defined like this.

**/application/libraries/Custom_library.php**

```
class Custom_library
{
    public function __construct($args = array()){
      //code here
    }
}
```

If `Custom_library` requires three params then you need to create and pass an associative array with three name/value pairs. In a controller it might look like this.

```
class Example extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //create an associative array
        $args = ['param1' => '1', 'param2' => '2', 'param3' => '3'];
        //pass array to library
        $this->load->library('custom_library', $args);
    }
}
```

To work with the above controller a more complete version of `Custom_library` might be defined like this

```
class Custom_library
{
    protected $foo;
    protected $bar;
    protected $baz;

    public function __construct($args = array())
    {
        if(!empty($args))
        {
            $this->foo = $args['param1'];
            $this->bar = $args['param2'];
            $this->baz = $args['param3'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand this,  so sometimes, those are third party Libraries and we don't want to modify them, They are just plug and play libraries. These libraries only expect you to pass those params

Comment: The $arg array is either indexed or associative. If the library specifies an indexed array then it is relying on the order they are added to the array. If the library specifies an associative array then the key to the array must match what the library expects - like the example in my answer. Or have I completely misunderstood your question?

Comment: Let me try to explain, say for instance, I want to pass the **value = 1 for argument 1** and the **value 5 for argument 2** and the **value 'argument 3' for argument 3**

Comment: I've expanded my answer to hopefully answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor will receive the array just in the same order as you filled it.

So when you do this:

```
$arg = ['param1' => '1', 'param2' => '2', 'param3' => '3'];
$this->load->library('MyLibrary', $arg);
```

Your constructor in your library must be like this:

```
public function __construct($args)
{
    // Do something with $args like:
    $this->var1 = $args['param1'];
    $this->var2 = $args['param2'];
    // etc
}
```

See docs for reference: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: Say It is a third party library and I don't want to go and modify the library, i just want to pass params and play

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment:

> I understand this, so sometimes, those are third party Libraries and
>   we don't want to modify them, They are just plug and play libraries.
>   These libraries only expect you to pass those params

if its a third-party library that you *don't* want to modify like DFriend suggested in his answer.

in the model/controller/base controller:

`require_once(APPPATH . '/third_party/somename.php);`

and then `new Somename($param1, $param2, $param3)` where you need it.

This is *not* how things should be done in CI (again DFriends answer is the best if you want to modify), but I understand sometimes people don't want to modify the library so updating or whatever is easy and you can use normal php this way in CI.